# Sampling StringName.SubString(p,1) for paragraph formatting character

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, automation, office-interop, paragraph

please try to specifically answer my question and not offer alternative approaches as I have a very specific problem that needs this ad-hoc solution. Thank you very much.

Automatically my code opens Word through VB.NET, opens the document, finds the table, goes to a cell, moves that cells.range.text into a String variable and in a For loop compares character at position p to a *String*.

I have tried *Strings*:
"^p", "^013", "U+00B6"

My code:

```
Dim nextString As String

    'For each cell, extract the cell's text.
    For p = 17 To word_Rng.Cells.Count
        nextString = word_Rng.Cells(p).Range.Text
        'For each text, search for structure.
        For q = 0 To nextString.Length - 1
            If (nextString.Substring(q, 1) = "U+00B6") Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
```

Is the structural data lost when assigning the cells text to a String variable. I have searched for formatting marks like this in VBA successfully in the past.

Comment: Seems VB.NET Strings do not include the character reference '00B6', hence no Pilcrow. Is there another data type i can cast the Word.Document.table.cell.range.text to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your string contains the character, you can use [`ChrW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to create the appropriate character from the hex value, and check for that:

```
If nextString.Substring(q, 1) = ChrW(&h00B6) Then
    Exit For
End If
```

**UPDATE**

Here's a complete example:

```
Dim nextString = "This is a test " & ChrW(&H00B6) & " for that char"
Console.WriteLine(nextString)

For q = 0 To nextString.Length - 1
    If nextString(q) = ChrW(&H00B6) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Found it: {0}", q)
    End If
Next
```

This outputs:

```
This is a test ¶ for that char
Found it: 15
```

Comment: I had done as you've now suggested Mark, before i commented on my question. It seems that the '&00B6 cannot be converted to Integer (my interpretation is that it is not included in the conversion table), and so the Pilcrow doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jimbo Not sure what you mean by "It seems that the '&00B6 cannot be converted to Integer", but make sure you are using &H00B6 - no quotes, and note the H - this is a hex constant.

Comment: Thank you so much! All that was missing was the 'H', why the hell don't the Microsoft examples (MSDN) include this?!